# Which is the best software for Android Development?

Tags: android, development-environment

Well i am trying to find a good software which helps me in coding. Hassle free and a bit helpy?

Comment: your **brain**, this is definitely the best tool, then **Android Studio**, nothing more

Comment: I think DOS is the best

Comment: Android Studio is the best, [http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html]

Answer (score 3):

As of now **eclipse** is generally used by most of the people around the world. You can download the same either from eclipse official site and download the plugin for the same

Or you can use **Android studio** for the same. To do the same you can download it from the official android developers site https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html .

Do keep in mind that after some time, android studio may be used more by people as it is developed only for android development and also google is stopping to provide support for eclipse.
One more thing that, once you download the software, you will need to install sdk's for the api level for which you want to develop
All the support for development for android is available at the above mentioned link. Information about all the libraries are also available at the same. For more resources, you can always use **youtube** for the possible leacture series and also use **stackoverflow** and **codata** whenever you are stuck.